# Excel sum data with same dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to check what is the total amount I paid each day the data is as follow's in my excel sheet

Check if the data is same and same filter is on then make a total in a separate column or in a separate workbook

I want to make total against each filter like what is total amount I paid as franchise payment and what is the amount I paid for mobilink.

[image: snap for excel sheet]

I have tried with couple of samples but not worked with my sheet.

Comment: So what do you want your result to look like?  If you just want a filtered list with totals, recommend making this an Excel table and turn on Total Row.

Comment: Pivot table should work for this

Answer (score 0):

You should create a pivot table.
Steps are as follows:
Select your entire table
Click on the INSERT tab and select PIVOTTABLE
Add type into the filter section which is on the right of the screen
Add date and payment in rows
Add total in values

Now you can use the filter to find the payments for franchise and mobilink.

I tried to explain as simple as possible. Will also add a sample screenshot of the pivot table you need to create on excel.
[PIVOT TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxmog.png)